# Selecting a given row in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

here is a simple problem. I have a table of 500 rows and what to be able to select a given row number n. This is what I am doing:

```
    select *
    from table
    where table.arg1 ='A'
    and time_stamp=to_date('1/8/2010','MM/DD/YYYY')
    and rownum = n
```

But it would only work for the row 1, for the rest it doesn't return anything. Any idea?

Comment: Your code sample could help, because I don't get why this wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't RowIndex used for the index in a table instead of rownum?. As far as I know this variable is only used in SQL Server 2005

Comment: Hi CommuSoft, I tried RowIndex and it says it is a invalid identifier

Comment: Will, I edited the question with the code sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why `where rownum = 3` returns an empty rowset is that the condition is not true for the first row.  For the second row, there is still no first row in the resultset, and `rownum` is still `1`.  So the condition fails again.  See [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html) for a more detailed explanation.

You can use `row_number()` in a subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select row_number() over (order by col1) as rn, yt.* 
    from YourTable yt
) sub
where rn = 3
```

Or even simpler, but perhaps more confusing, using `rownum` itself:

```
select *
from (
    select rownum as rn, yt.* 
    from YourTable yt
) sub
where rn = 3
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar it worked perfectly!! That forum is really good!